# How do you fix gap between img and left side of screen and mismatched navbar options?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have made my logo for my website and I have added it in, but I am having some problems.

1. When in fullscreen on a large device, the logo image does not touch the left side of the screen. There is a gap between the img.
2. When in fullscreen on a large device, the logo is on one line and the navigation options are on another line. (I have a collapsed nav bar on small devices. It looks very good on the small device, but terrible on a large device.)

http://bmwent.codehs.me/

Expected Results:

1. No gap on the side part of the navbar between the image and the left side of the screen.
2. The image and the navigation options should be on the same line.

Thank you.